# Postgresql to mbtiles

Tags: openstreetmap, tiles, mbtiles, mapproxy, tile-server

Someboby please help me with understanding of the following question.
I have many postgreSQL databases with osm data on a server. Each of them contains the map of the certain country. I want to look through the maps on my notebook via offline WMS client. Can I convert databases to .mbtiles for tileserver or is there another way for a best perfomance?

Comment: Convert your database to geopackage- or spatialite or vector pbf mbtiles or raster tiles. Use QGIS or OGR2Ogr to convert to gpkg features use it create GEOJSON and then tippecsnoe to make vector tiles

Answer (score 1):

Let us start from the basics. Your postgis database contains the vectors that make up your features.

Mbtiles is a special format which stores tiles that make up a map. It is a representation of the data rather than the data itself.

You need some way of converting from the data to this rendered tileset in Mbtiles format.

To do this you need a software like say tilemill which is used to design maps and create rendered tiles.

Comment: that is right. I thought about mapproxy which could use mbtiles as tile storage instead of mapnik+postgis db. OK! Anyway i'll look at tilemill then. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with @Devdatta Tengshe idea but then you'd have to go through a format conversion.  You can [run postgreSQl without a full installation](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/172-Starting-PostgreSQL-in-windows-without-install.html).  I've used that before.  You can export your Postgres database and import it on you laptop.  What I like about the running without install idea, is that if you don't want your Postgres service running, then just don't start the batch file/shell script.

Comment: Thaks, Greg I've already active used it. the idea was in a changing the postgres data to the tiles. Mbtiles is just the way of using tile storage. I believed that it affected on the map perfomance

Answer (score 0):

Why not just view them with a GIS? QGIS can, obviously, read direct from PostGIS.

If you render them as tiles, you certainly can view them on your laptop, but you can't get more info that what you have used to style the layers.

Perhaps you should rephrase your question, and state what you're trying to achieve, without proposing half a solution too!

Answer (score 0):

QGIS has a tool  `Raster tools\Generate XYZ tiles (MBTiles)` since version 3.8. In version 3.10 tool was changed to use multithreading, so it is much faster on a modern machine.

[See online help for tool description](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rastertools.html#generate-xyz-tiles-mbtiles)

Be careful with zoom levels - especially maximum zoom. File size can become really big with high zoom levels. Zoom levels up to 16 are reasonable for smaller countries. I usually check zoom levels on online OSM map. See example for zoom level 16 - indicated in **bold** [https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=**16**/46.0762/14.4833](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=16/46.0762/14.4833)

Higher value for  `metatile size` will result in faster processing and less artefacts. I usually use maximum value of `20` on machine with 32 GB of system memmory.